# Read a particular info and write to a txt file using java

Tags: java

am new to java programming I need a program to read a certain information from a file and select the particular informationwhich is needed and then write this particular information into a text file .

{

```
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (newFileReader("C:/Users/ngorentl/"));
    String info = "";
    String info1 = "";
    int startLine = 111 ;
    int endLine = 203 ;
    int sl = 221;
    int el =325;
```

// reading only the specific info which is needed and  that is printing in the console

```
   for (int i = 0; i < startLine; i++) { info = in.readLine(); }
    for (int i = startLine; i < endLine + 1; i++) {
        info = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(info);
    }
       for (int j = 203; j < sl; j++) { info1 = in.readLine(); }
        for (int j = sl; j < el + 1; j++) {
            info1 = in.readLine();
           System.out.println(info1);
        }

     // having a problem from here i dont know whether this is the correct approach 
        File fin = new File(info); // getting an error here
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fin);
        BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));     
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("hh.txt");
        OutputStreamWriter osw= new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
        String aLine = null;
        while ((aLine = is.readLine()) != null) {
        bw.write(aLine);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
        is.close();
        }
        in.close();
```

}

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: that's why am seeking help

Comment: You are not seeking help. You are asking us to write code

Comment: I have edited my question with the code am trying i hope you'll get an idea now

Comment: You are closing the streams after the first read line, you should close them after the `while` loop .

Comment: OK is that the only mistake because i see a error here  File fin = new File(info);

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885173/how-do-i-create-a-file-and-write-to-it-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File fin = new File(String fileName) is the correct syntax.
eg.
File fin = new File("C:\abc.txt");

[UPDATE]
Assuming your question is about writing a String to file.
In Java 7

```
try(  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter( "filename.txt" )  ){
out.println( info); 
}
```

In Java 6 or below, use

```
try {
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("sample.txt"));
        out.write(info);
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception ");       
    }
```

and possible correction of your code, so variable info has all that **information**

```
for (int i = startLine; i < endLine + 1; i++) {
    info    +=   in.readLine();
}

    System.out.println(info);
```

Comment: my information is stored in "info" so how can i specify in the syntax ?

Comment: You're making a simple job rather complex by your terminologies. What is this "info" you're talking about?
Suppose following is the content zin.txt.
"Abc def dog cat xyz opqr
qwerty hah lee law tekken
pass
ip 10.10.20.33
abcdef some other text"

Comment: info = in.readLine(); ---> which ever information needed i've stored it in here in the "info" now how do i write it into a text file.

Comment: only the last line of my info is writing